# How to get the total of sales and commission distributed to different users in single query?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have following Tables in my database:

```
    Sales
   ---------------------------------------------
    id  client  account sale Commission
    1   X       A2      400     100 
    2   X       A2      300     70
    3   X       A1      1100        100
    4   X       A1      1200        200

    Account                         Users
    --------------------            -------------------------------------
    accountid   account             id      username first_name last_name
    A1          Acc1                U1      abc      Manish     Goyal
    A2          Acc2                U2      xyz      Yogita     Sharma
    A3          Acc3                U3      jkl      Nitish     Malhotra        

    AccountUsers
    ----------------------------------------
    id  accountid       user        Commission(commission_percentage)
    1   A1              U1             70
    2   A1              U2             20
    3   A1              U3             10
```

I want to get the Sum of sale column and commission column from sales table whose commission is distributed in Associated Account's different users.

I wrote the following SQL

```
SELECT users.id as user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, 
accounts.account_name as account_name, accounts.accountid as account_id, 
SUM(sales.sale) AS sales, 
SUM(sales.commission) AS commission, 
FROM sales 
INNER JOIN accounts ON sales.account = accounts.accountid 
INNER JOIN AccountUsers ON AccountUsers.accountid = Accounts.accountid 
INNER JOIN Users ON Users.id = AccountUsers.user 
GROUP BY Accounts.accountid ,Users.id WITH ROLLUP HAVING (Accounts.accountid IS NOT NULL)
```

I got the following Result:

```
user_id     first_name  last_name   account_name    sales   commission
U1          Manish      Goyal       ACC1            2300        210
U2          Yogita      Sharma      ACC1            2300        60
U3          Nitish      Malhotra    ACC1            2300        30
NULL        Nitish      Malhotra    ACC1            6900        300
```

However, I want to get following result:

```
Output
user_id     first_name  last_name   account_name    sales   commission
U1          Manish      Goyal       ACC1            2300        210
U2          Yogita      Sharma      ACC1            2300        60
U3          Nitish      Malhotra    ACC1            2300        30
NULL        Nitish      Malhotra    ACC1            2300        300
```

I want the desired output in single query because i also fetch overall grand total. In my database tables there are thousands of records. To get this scenario i have to execute query for twice one for detail output and one for grand total.

```
Here is a sum up of above example : 

    For ACC1 (A1) account, in Sales table total sales and commission are 2300 and 300 respectively. 
For U1 (Manish Goyal) user, user commission distribution for this user in AccountUsers table is 70 so therefore tatal sale will be 2300 and commission will be (300*70)/100 = 210. 
For U2 (Yogita Sharma) user, user commission distribution for this user in AccountUsers table is 20 so therefore tatal sale will be 2300 and commission will be (300*20)/100 = 60.
For U3 (Nitish Malhotra) user, user commission distribution for this user in AccountUsers table is 10 so therefore tatal sale will be 2300 and commission will be (300*10)/100 = 30.

when mysql query run with group by clause with rollup having accountid is not null return the grand total of sales(6900) and commissiom(300).
```

**what i want is grand total for sales should be 2300.**

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you explain those `210`,`60`,`30` and `300` values in the last column? Also, why `NULL` for `user_id` in the last row instead of `U3` ?

Comment: Total Commission return from percentage calculate mysql function. In this function it returns (commission * users_percentage)/100. For Example : For A1 for U3 is account total commission is (  (200*10)100  = 20 and (100*10)/100 = 10 ) = 30

Comment: Can you give an example with respect to any user here?

Comment: The Last Row with null User return because group by with roll up.

Comment: For emample : for ACC1 (A1) account, in Sales table total sales and commission are 2300 and 300 respectively. for U1 (Manish Goyal) user, user commission distribution for this user in AccountUsers table is 70 so therefore tatal sale will be 2300 and commission will be (300*70)/100 = 210.

Comment: Makes sense now. Why last row has a `300` for `Nitish`? Can you explain?

Comment: You may use union in this case, but it doesn't make sense to combine 2 logically different result sets. If you don't want to query twice, then just do an [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) on last 2 columns in PHP to get total sales and total commission.

Comment: Here is example for only one user without any filters. There are hundred of users and thousands of record in sales  associated with multiple accounts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188106/discussion-between-yogita-sharma-and-vivek-23).

Comment: Use PHP if you don't want to query twice